# Use relative path for both jquery load and direct link to html page

Tags: jquery, html, load, relative-path, absolute-path

On my website I use links to load html pages within a div.

```
<a class="iframe" href="portfolio/1/1.html">Link</a>
```

code

```
$(".iframe").on("click", function() {
   var $mylink = $(this).attr('href');
   $div.load($mylink);
}
```

If I open one of those links in a new tab, css and images do not load because I use relative paths since the html pages end up inside a div.
By using absolute paths on the html pages I can get them to load but that causes css to load twice when the links load inside the div (and not on a new tab).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<img src="portfolio/1/1.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to use relative paths only and come around this issue? Basically I want the html pages to load inside the div as they do, but if the user opens the html page directly to still be able to load the content correctly (without using absolute paths if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the base tag to specify a base url. All relative links within a html document will be relative to your base https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Do I have to add it on each html page? if so how does it differ from absolute path?

Comment: You need to add the base tag once in the HEAD section of the pages you want to work in a new tab. Without a base tag, relative links in the document are relative to the current window location - thus when in a new tab your relative css link for example points to yourdomain.com/portfolio/1/css/main.css. With a base set, all relative links are relative to the base, eg if you have yourdomain.com set as the base in your html, the relative css link points to yourdomain.com/css/main.css irrespective of the window location. I hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried it, but it creates the same problem as absolute paths, when the link is loaded inside the div the css loads twice (I am guessing the images as well).

Comment: Maybe I could use jquery to remove the base tag when the link is loaded within the div?

Comment: My solution should only help your css and images work in a new tab. The iframe cannot be affected by the stylesheets present in the page containing it, so the file will be loaded once again. Most browsers will load this from cache rather than fetching from the server. Or did you mean the css file loads three times - once in the parent page and twice in the iframe?

Comment: I can see two of the same css tags in the browser inspector for each element (when loaded in the div), which made me think it requests all the css and images from the html pages twice, but doesn't seem so when recording with browser's inspector. Is this correct or does it actually affect loading?

Comment: Just noticed another issue with base href, when sharing the html page on social media the images are not used for preview (it's empty). Is there any way around this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185424/discussion-between-davyww-and-zefs).